# Comparing two integers and insert a comparison sign <,>= between the two numbers

Tags: c, math

I would like to compare two positive integers and add a comparison sign between them. I may not use any `logical`, `relational` or `bitwise operators` and  no `if` then `else` or `while` loop  or  ternary operator.

I found the `max` and `min` of these two numbers.

> How can  I preserve the order and still insert the comparison sign? Any ideas?

E.g.:

`4 6` was entered by user output must be `4 < 6`

`10 2` was entered by user output must be `10 > 2`

`2 2` was entered by user output must be `2 = 2`

```
f1 = x / y;
f2 = y / x;

f1 = (f1 + 2) % (f1 + 1);
f2 = (f2 + 2) % (f2 + 1);

max = f1  * x + f2 * y ;
max = max / (f1 + f2);
```

Comment: What did you try?  What is the minimum reproducible code you wrote?  What do you mean when you say you don't "use any logical, relational and bitwise operators and no if then else or while loop"?

Comment: How did you find the max and min? You said that, you didn't use any logical, relational and bitwise operators and no if then else or while loop??

Comment: @BlackBird it's doable with fmax and fmin.

Comment: @user3528438 But we shouldn't have to be guessing what the OP did, they should have shown code.

Comment: Yes. 2 2 entered by user and output must be 2=2 . All input will be positive integers only.

Comment: Why not do this with an `if...else` statement? It will only be 4 lines of code.

Comment: Under so many limitations (challenges), I think this is a **code golf** question so please move it there. [link](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ABK197 You didn't exclude the use of `for` loop. Did you forget that? PS: my answer is edited again. Please accept it if it answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an array of char:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned a, b;
    scanf("%u %u", &a, &b);

    size_t cmp = (_Bool)(a / b) - (_Bool)(b / a);
    char relation = "<=>"[cmp + 1];
    printf("%u %c %u\n", a, relation, b);

    return 0;
}
```

This approach don't require `min` and `max` found out.

## Explanation:

1. `(_Bool)exp` will be 1 if `exp` is non-zero, and 0 if `exp` equals to 0.
2. Since `a` and `b` are positive integers, `a / b` will be 0 when `a < b`, and 1 when `a >= b`. See the truth table below for details.

> ```
>         (_Bool)(a / b)    (_Bool)(b / a)     (_Bool)(a / b) - (_Bool)(b / a)
>
> a > b          1                 0                          1
>
> a = b          1                 1                          0
>
> a < b          0                 1                         -1
> ```

3. As a result, `cmp` evaluates to `-1, 0, 1`, like a typical comparison function. And thus, `cmp + 1` will conveniently lead to `0, 1, 2` valid array indexes.

Thanks @janos for [his help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/120688/96221).

## Edit:

As @chux carefully points out,

> OP stated "I may not use any logical, ... operators". The C spec has
>   "... the logical negation operator !...". §6.5.3.3 5. Using ! may not
>   meet OP's goals.

So I changed `!!exp` to `(_Bool)exp` to meet OP's demand.

## Edit II:

OP commented:

> Thanks. This does not work when one of the inputs is 0.

But isn't the input numbers granted to be positive? Well, to handle zeros you can use `size_t cmp = (_Bool)((a + (_Bool)(a - UINT_MAX)) / (b + (_Bool)(b - UINT_MAX))) - (_Bool)((b + (_Bool)(b - UINT_MAX)) / (a + (_Bool)(a - UINT_MAX)));`. Don't forget to `#include <limits.h>`.

## EDIT III (The last edit, I hope):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define ISEQUAL(x, y) (_Bool)((_Bool)((x) - (y)) - 1) // 1 if x == y, 0 if x != y
#define NOTEQUAL(x, y) (_Bool)((x) - (y)) // 0 if x == y, 1 if x != y

int main(void)
{
    unsigned a, b;
    printf("%u\n", UINT_MAX);
    scanf("%u %u", &a, &b);

    _Bool hasZero = NOTEQUAL(ISEQUAL(a, 0) + ISEQUAL(b, 0), 0);
    _Bool hasMax = NOTEQUAL(ISEQUAL(a, UINT_MAX) + ISEQUAL(b, UINT_MAX), 0);
    int hasBoth = ISEQUAL(hasZero + hasMax, 2);
    int cmp = (_Bool)((a + hasZero + hasBoth) / (b + hasZero + hasBoth))\
            - (_Bool)((b + hasZero + hasBoth) / (a + hasZero + hasBoth));
    // "+ hasZero + hasBoth" to avoid div 0: UINT_MAX -> 1, while 0 -> 2.
    hasBoth =  1 - hasBoth * 2; // 1 if hasBoth == 0, or -1 if hasBoth == 1
    char relation = "<=>"[hasBoth * cmp + 1]; // reverse if has both 0 and UINT_MAX
    printf("%u %c %u\n", a, relation, b);

    return 0;
}
```

1. Fixed a bug when a == UINT_MAX - 1 and b == UINT_MAX at @chux points out.
2. Used macro to improve readability.
3. Added some comments.

Comment: You might receive more upvotes if you: 1. Explain how the `!!(a/b)` hack works; 2. Explain how `!!(a/b) - !!(b/a)` evaluates to -1, 0, 1, like a typical comparison function, 3. and that +1 to the result of `cmp` will conveniently lead to 0, 1, 2 valid array indexes. Good luck!

Comment: @janos Answer updated. Thank you for your warm help!

Comment: OP stated "I may not use any logical, ...  operators".  The C spec has "... the logical negation operator `!`...".  §6.5.3.3 5.  Using `!` may not meet OP's goals.

Comment: Nice improvement.  I suspect the powers-that-be that gave OP this problem will grumble about the use of `(_Bool)`.  Yet I see no restriction against casting operators.  So it should be acceptable - unless, sigh, another restriction comes along.

Comment: @chux Thanks, improved :-)

Comment: Thanks. This does not work when one of the inputs is 0.

Comment: @ABK197 It does not need to work with 0.  Question is about "compare two positive integers".

Comment: @ABK197 Edited to handle zeros.

Comment: `(a + 1LLU) / (b + 1)` --> `(a + 1LLU) / (b + 1LLU)` in two places, else `A or B == UINT_MAX` causes div/0.

Comment: @chux Edited again ;-)

Comment: Needs work: `a=UINT_MAX-1; b=UINT_MAX;` --> cmp == 0.  Shifting by `n` only works if both a,b, shift by the same `n`.

Answer (score 4):

As OP has `x`, `y` and has computed their minimum `min` and maximum `max`

```
void prt(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned min, unsigned max) {
  // min not used
  unsigned cmp = 1 + x/max - y/max;
  printf("%u %c %u\n", x, "<=>"[cmp],  y);
}
```

Comment: Took me two minutes to understand `"<=>"[cmp]`, +1 nice shortcut!

Comment: @user3528438 `max == 0` is not expected as OP asserted "... compare two positive integers ...".

Comment: If one of the inputs is zero, what approach to take ?

Comment: @ABK197  With "compare two positive integers" and now asking about "If one of the inputs is zero", are you looking to change the question?  Suggest positing a new question instead where the premise is "compare two non-negative integers" or "compare two `unsigned`"

Comment: Sorry . You are right. I should have asked compare two negative integers as that is what I wanted.

Comment: @ABK197  I think your best bet is to leave the question unchanged.  Perhaps try to resolve other cases yourself as SO appears to not have received this question well.  Take more time on your next question to think it out clearly and do more research too.  Good luck,

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
static unsigned int cmpgt(const unsigned int a, const unsigned int b)
{
    return b?(a/b ? (a-b):0):a;
    // if B is 0, then return A. non zero A will be treated as true
    //            if a is zero then is false
    // if b is not zero then do a/b, if non zero then return (a-b)
    //            non zero (a-b) will be treated as true
    //            if (a-b) is zero then will be treated as false
    //
    // This is a very ugly way of implementing operator >
    // There are other ways to do it
    // But the point is, you need operator >, but you can not use it
    // ( for whatever reason), then you just make it, which is doable
}
static const char *mark(const unsigned int a, const unsigned int b)
{
    return cmpgt(a, b)?">":(cmpgt(b,a)?"<":"=");
    // no if-else, but ternary operator is a good alternative
    // so those are two nested operator ?:
    // basically :
    // if a>b then return ">"
    // else if a<b return "<"
    // else return "="
    // with cmpgt/operator > implemented, this is a lot easier          
}
int main(void) {
    const int input[] = {1,3,4,5,5,2,3,4}; //test input
    size_t input_size = sizeof(input)/sizeof(int);
    for (size_t i=0;cmpgt(input_size-1, i);i++){
        // while loop is banned, but for loop is still usable
        // the loop condition is handled by cmpgt
        printf("%d %s ",input[i],mark(input[i], input[i+1]));
    }
    printf("%d\n", input[input_size-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

sample output:

```
1 < 3 < 4 < 5 = 5 > 2 < 3 < 4
```

https://ideone.com/dFHWnn

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use `if (a > b) {
        return ">"
    } else if (a == b) {
        return "="
    } else {
        return "<"
    }`?

Comment: Is it possible to do the same without using ternary operator?

Comment: @royhowie I don't know but it's a requirement in the original question.

Comment: @user3528438 Oh. I didn't see that. That's bizarre and a waste of time.

Comment: @royhowie it certainly is.

Comment: @ABK197 Yes, if you can implement comparison more cleanly ( return 1 on true, 0 on false), then you can use case/switch. But such a clean implementation of comparison within the limitations is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

A simple compare is to use `<=`, `>=` and then lookup the compare character from a string.

```
void cmp1(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  int cmp = (x >= y) - (x <= y);
  printf("%u %c %u\n", x, "<=>"[cmp + 1],  y);
}
```

Yet since we cannot use various operators, etc., All we need to do is replace `>=`.

```
_Bool foo_ge(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  _Bool yeq0 = 1 - (_Bool)y;        // y == 0?
  _Bool q = (x + yeq0)/(y + yeq0);  // Offset both x,y, by yeq0
  return q + yeq0;
}

void cmp2(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  int cmp = foo_ge(x,y) -  foo_ge(y,x)
  printf("%u %c %u\n", x, "<=>"[cmp + 1],  y);
}
```

Heavy use of `_Bool` credit to  [@sun qingyao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35533732/2410359)